# WebDriverEventListener take screenshot onException()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

guys. Today I have done my custom realization for WebDriverEventListener. I need only onException() method which will create screenshot. But I got problem because I am using fluent wait.

```
new FluentWait<>(webDriver)
    .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .until(someCondition)
```

So, finally, I have got screen for each ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) - 20 screenshots for 1 fail ))). Had somebody the such problem or had someone resolve it?

Comment: seems like you need to ignore nosuchelement too... the wait would throw timeout if the element never shows up.

Comment: Yes, until() throws TimeoutException, but after 10 seconds. The question was about WebDriverEventListener with method onException(). Every 500 milliseconds I will get  NoSuchElementException which should be ignored during 10 seconds. But the method onException() makes screenshot every 500 millis instead 1 time after 10 seconds. It is a problem...

Comment: If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, you should only take a screenshot when the `TimeoutException` is thrown.

Comment: Hi, @ Ardesco. webDriver.takeScreenshot() fails, if page is not loaded. In this case I shouldn't take screenshots. But, ExpectedCondition class call webDriver.findElement() and it throws an exception every `.pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))` milliseconds. In this case onException() method will be called ache 500 ms as well. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)` you don't avoid that the exception is raised, you are just ignoring that exception. What is happening is that the exception is being raised by your FluentWait, but it is ignored (when you declare `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)`).

You have three options here:

- Capture the screen at the end of your test if the test failed [**preferred**].
- Have a Try-Catch wherever you are using your FluentWait or any other Selenium code.
- Use reflection to avoid capture when the event is raised from the method that implements the FluentWait.

This is an idea after what we have discussed:

```
private void ExceptionThrown(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ThrownException is NoSuchElementException)
    {
        // Get the stack trace from the current exception
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace(e.ThrownException, true);

        // Get the method stack frame index.
        int stackTraceIndex = stackTrace.FrameCount - 1;

        // Get the method name that caused the exception 
        string methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTraceIndex).GetMethod().Name;

        if(methodName != "MyFindElement")
        {
            TakeSceenshot();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TakeSceenshot();
    }
}

// This is an extension method of the DriverHelper interface
public IWebElement MyFindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeOut = 0)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    // I wait until the element exist
    IWebElement result = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by) != null);
    // it means that the element doesn't exist, so we throw the exception
    if(result == null) 
    {
        MyPersonalException(by);
    }
}

// The parameter will help up to generate more accurate log
public void MyPersonalException(By by)
{
    throw new NoSuchElementException(by.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi, @charlie.mtp, thanks for you response. So, by steps :) :
1. Capture the screen at the end of your test - yes, sure, I have done it already :) But... If we are talking about 'very good site' it fails. Example - I have set 25 seconds to be sure that site is loaded. WebDriver throws TimeoutException and goes to `getScreenshotAs()` method. Then it continue wait 60 seconds and again fails with TimeoutException and without screenshot. This is the main idea why I tried to use 'onException()' method, because  `if (throvable instanse of TimeoutException)` I will skip screenshot.

Comment: 2. Have a Try-Catch - could be, but not global variant. It not useful for whole project.

Comment: 3. Use reflection - It is hard to identify when FluentWait ignoring each exception and when it throws the last. Now I am trying to done in such way. 
Thanks :)

Comment: And, finally, as I can see this is a global FluentWait problem and I hope Selenium team will think how it could be resolve.

Comment: Hi @SlavaLubarskyi, you do know what is the last exception. It depends on how you use your FluentWait. You can expect a timeout or the function returns null. So again, using reflection you can ignore all the `NoSuchElementException` from the FluentWait function and only raise the one related with timeout or when that function returns null.

Comment: Hi, @charlie.mtp.
1. I have to take screenshot in case of `NoSuchElementException`. 
2. About FluentVait
`.withTimeout`('5 seconds') - will wait 5 seconds in worst variant;
`.pollingEvery`('1 second') - will call webDriver.findBy() every 1 second AND here will be thrown NoSuchElementException if element is not find, then will be call `WebDriverEventListener.onException()` method where I can ingore some exceptions but not NoSuchElementException and going to take screenshot.


3. About reflaction - it is hard to identify the last NoSuchElementException.

Comment: `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)` - this ignors in exception and it is necessary for FluentWait works. If it will remove FluentWait will be 1 second instead 5.
`.until('condition')`

Comment: Hi @SlavaLubarskyi, I updated my answer with a piece of code from C# that might help you. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I think that `drv.FindElement(by)` will throw exception and this problem I am going to solve. Finally, I find another variant. Finally, I have found another variant. I have override ExpectedCondition methods - instead `driver.findBy()` I am going to use `driver.findElements().size > 0` and if result is null I will throw exception. But this approach should be tested more. In addition I have extended WebDriver and realized it through proxy.

Comment: It is going to throw an exception but **ExceptionThrown** method is going to handle it. Check that we are ignoring every exception from **MyFindElement**

Comment: Yes, I see. But how you are going to identity the **last one**. Because I have to ignore 19 exceptions and **only then** call onException() method. If you are going to count it then it will fail in cases when FluentWait duration changes. As I can see it doesn't have default solution, so, there are possible few workarounds :)

Answer (score 0):

This probably require changes in EventFiringWebDriver, because this class is without WebDriverWait instance and events for them. If you want avoid it, create bool variable in your EventFiringWebDriver extended class and check this value in your OnException like:

```
protected void OnException(WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e) {
            if (IsWaitHandler)
                return;

            Your actions... 
}
```

but this is not perfect solution.